# Ошибка cannot set property onclick of null JS

Tags: javascript

Хотел сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку текст выводился в консоли, но ничего не происходит из за ошибки:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null
```

Много чего пробовал, но ничего не вышло.

```
let themeButton = document.querySelector('.theme-button');
themeButton.onclick = function () {
  console.log('How_are_you?');  
};

<button class="theme-button" type="button">Hello, pidr</button>
```

Comment: а у вас только одна кнопка с таким классом?

Comment: Нужно проверить: 1) значение themeButton 2) наличие элемента с классом `theme-button` 3) код вызывается после построения DOM

Comment: Komdosh да одна

Comment: у меня работает, похоже вам нужно выполнить 3 пункт от коммента @gil9red

Comment: Спасибо gil9red и Komdosh, я разобрался

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Такое может происходить если Вы обращаетесь к элементу который еще нет, что бы это решить можно привязаться к event'у [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event), который будет ждать пока DOM не будет построен и только после этого начнет выполнение Вашего скрипта:

```js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", event => {
  console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed")
  const themeButton = document.querySelector(".theme-button")

  const handleClick = () => {
    console.log("How are you?")
  }

  themeButton.addEventListener("click", handleClick)
})
```

```html
<button class="theme-button" type="button">Hello, man!</button>
```